# Change recyclerview for listview?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-listview

I have a response from the database that contains a list of response-items, these response-items contain 4 different types of lists. What I want to do is ask what type of list comes in each object and inflate the view with the corresponding list.

I did this with a vertical recyclerview that contains other horizontal recyclerviews depending on the list. I got it to work but when doing the vertical scroll, the one of the recycler that contains the others, it gets stuck a bit, the movement is not fluid, as if it was difficult for it to process quickly.

My question is, shouldn't I change that recyclerview to a listview? It would take longer to load but everything would already be loaded and the scroll would be smoother. Or am I wrong?
the horizontal scroll of the recyclerviews of each list runs smoothly and without problems. each horizontal recycler list has 10 items

here is my homefragment

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_home) {

private lateinit var binding: FragmentHomeBinding
private val viewModel by viewModels<CustomerViewModel> {
    CustomerViewModelFactory(ApiCallsRepositoryImpl(DataSource(RetrofitClient.webservice)))
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    binding = FragmentHomeBinding.bind(view)




    viewModel.fetchDataInicio().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { result ->
        when (result) {
            is Resource.Loading -> {
                Log.d("LiveDataFetchDataInicio", "Loading")
            }


            is Resource.Success -> {
                LoadDataHome(result)
            }

            is Resource.Failure -> {
                Log.d("ErrorFetchDataInicio", "${result.exception}")
            }
        }
    })




}

private fun LoadDataHome(result: Resource.Success<HomeResponse>) {
    Log.d("SuccessFetchDataInicio", "${result.data}")
    val itemlist = mutableListOf<HomeResponseItem>()
    itemlist.addAll(result.data)
    val adapterPrincipal = HomeResponseAdapter(itemlist)
    binding.rvPrincipal.layoutManager =
        LinearLayoutManager(
            binding.root.context,
            LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,
            false
        )
    binding.rvPrincipal.adapter = adapterPrincipal
    adapterPrincipal.notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

}
and this is the adapter of the recyclerview

```
class HomeResponseAdapter(private val itemList: List<HomeResponseItem>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    when (viewType) {
        1 -> {
            val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_pill_button_view, parent, false)
            return PillButtonCarouselViewHolder(view)
        }
        2 ->{
            val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_card_product_view, parent, false)
            return ProductsCarouselViewHolder(view)
        }
        3 -> {
            val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_mini_banner_view, parent, false)
            return MiniBannerCaruoselViewHolder(view)
        }
        4 ->{
            val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_square_banner_view, parent, false)
            return SquareBannerCaruoselViewHolder(view)
        }
        else ->{
            return EmptyViewHolder(View(parent.context))
        }

    }
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val item = itemList[position]

    when (holder.itemViewType) {
        1 -> {
            val listaPillButton = item.contenido!!.pillButtons ?: listOf()
            val tipo2ViewHolder = holder as PillButtonCarouselViewHolder
            tipo2ViewHolder.bind(listaPillButton)
        }
        2 -> {
            val listapProductsData = item.contenido!!.productos ?: listOf()
            val tipo3ViewHolder = holder as ProductsCarouselViewHolder
            tipo3ViewHolder.bind(listapProductsData)
        }
        3 -> {
            val listaMiniBanner = item.contenido!!.miniBanners ?: listOf()
            val tipo1ViewHolder = holder as MiniBannerCaruoselViewHolder
            tipo1ViewHolder.bind(listaMiniBanner)
        }
        4 -> {
            val listaSquareBanner = item.contenido!!.squareBanners ?: listOf()
            val tipo4ViewHolder = holder as SquareBannerCaruoselViewHolder
            tipo4ViewHolder.bind(listaSquareBanner)
        }

    }
}

override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {

    return when(itemList[position].idContenido){
        "SquareBanners"-> 4
        "PillButtons"->1
        "MiniBanners"->3
        "Productos"->2
        else -> 5
    }

}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return itemList.size
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Moving to ListView won't be good of a solution. ListView loads all the items into memory while RecyclerView only loads the items that are currently visible. If your dataset is large, ListView could potentially consume more memory and lead to an `OutOfMemoryError`.

There are a few things which can improve the performances-

1. Use setHasFixedSize(true): If you know the RecyclerView's size doesn't depend on the adapter content, set the following to improve performance
2. If your inner recyclerViews has complex operations, then you can process those in a separate thread and update the UI in the main thread. You can use a handler or Executors.
3. If your data needs processing for showing, you can use a shimmering view to hold the user for a certain amount of time in which the data will be processed.

Answer (score 0):

Always override `getItemId` , solves most problems.

Comment: you mean performance problems? Why?

Comment: It helps the recyclerview to identify items properly, and perform operations properly and maybe more efficiently, and also use `setHasStableIds(true)` and make use the binding methods are as light as possible